# What are the coordinates of the center of rotation of our galaxy, relative to ourselves?

Tags: astronomy, milky-way

So standing outside in the garden, can we physically point to the center of rotation of the galaxy?
I understand that from our viewpoint on Earth, it would be a moving point, so allowing for Earth rotation and orbits of the Sun and Earth, can we now pinpoint the galactic center?

Comment: Would [astronomy.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: The first part is definitively not broad. The answer is yes and it is close to Sagittarius, which the author of the question should have found on his own by a little research. Concerning the last two questions: that is quite broad. What can we point at? Well, almost everything except the guy over there; that would be impolite pointing at him. What is the best thing about it? Looking at stars at night, my wife serves hot tea. Quite broad, I would say.

Comment: Alayax, Your question might be reopened if you delete the last two sentences. Regarding the first question, read the wikipedia article on [Sagittarius A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagittarius_A*).

Comment: So, in virtual or augmented reality, we could put up a signpost to point to the center of the Galaxy, or Alpha Proxima, or the theoretical rotation center of Galaxy clusters? I was trying to convey the idea without giving the business model away.

Comment: You can't put up a signpost fixed to the Earth's surface that points to these locations.  You can identify a point relative to the stars that points to these locations, or any other outside the solar system.  Have you gone outside at night and noticed that the stars you see change from day to day and hour to hour?

Comment: Yes Ross. Those changes are what  I want to plot. So once we have a decent VR headset, we can have a app that shows a high resolution I rendered image, in the correct location, and orientation minus all the dust  in the way. One or more galactic  orientation point in the sky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What? Like this? Credit & Copyright: Yuri Beletsky (ESO).

[image: VLT points to the Galactic Center: Credit & Copyright: Yuri Beletsky (ESO).]

The 3D coordinates of the Galactic Center are generally taken as those of the Sagittarius A* radio source (the G.C. is behind too much dust to see anything at visible wavelengths). These are [right ascension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_ascension) 17h45m40s  and [declination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declination) -29d00m28s and at a radial distance from the solar system of about 8000 pc (26,000 light years, but with an uncertainty of about 5%).

Comment: Yes, Thank you Rob, that answers the question perfectly.. The 5% can be accounted for.